# After comparing bitmap object, how to get next bitmap object continuously using button's click?

Tags: android, button, bitmap

**Originally my first bitmap object I get from previous activity, and compare with another bitmap in same activity. I done bitmap comparison on button's click (called Next), but I faced one problem. When I click on button(Next) then one time bitmap object change after comparison. I want to continously change bitmap object using button's click(Next). Below is my code which I has been done.**

```
//I use bundle extra for getting bitmap object from previous activity

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap img_A = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_a);
                Bitmap img_B = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_b);

                Bitmap img_C = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_c);

                Bitmap img_D = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_d);

if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_A)){
                        bitmap = img_B.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_B)){
                        bitmap = img_C.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_C)){
                        bitmap = img_D.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


}
});
```

**And this is imagesAreEqual(),**

```
boolean imagesAreEqual(Bitmap i1, Bitmap i2)
    {
        if (i1.getHeight() != i2.getHeight())
        return false;
        if (i1.getWidth() != i2.getWidth()) return false;

        for (int y = 0; y < i1.getHeight(); ++y)
           for (int x = 0; x < i1.getWidth(); ++x)
                if (i1.getPixel(x, y) != i2.getPixel(x, y)) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is this an **I'm too lazy. Do this for me plx!** question, or have you actually tried something to iterate the images?

Comment: i add image for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I don't really get you point with this question, but I think you should try to get the new byteArray[] for the bmp after you are through with one loop.

Or can you somehow call this thread (what then is no longer necessary) whenever the byteArray changes, so you don't have to check 30 times/s, what might really save you some battery.

Or, if that is not possible check like 30 times/s if the byteArray has changed, and only if, check if it is the same as one of the others.

but I don't really know if I really got your problem, so just comment if not.

Edit: you wanted some code, so here comes:

```
public class myActivity implements Runnable{
    private Thread thread;
    public boolean running = false;
    private Bitmap oldbmp;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

    public void setRunning(boolean setRunning){
        running = setRunning;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(running){
            //Start Time
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            if(!bmp.equals(oldbmp){
                 if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_A)){
                    bitmap = img_B.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 } else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_B)){
                     bitmap = img_C.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                     image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 } else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_C)){
                     bitmap = img_D.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                     image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 } else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_D)){
                     bitmap = img_D.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                     image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 }

                //End Time
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (endTime -startTime < 1000/30){
                    try 
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000/2 -(endTime -startTime));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credits to @TomTsagk

so here's some code what should work if added correctly. 
It checks every half a second if the bmp has changed, and if, looks if there is one of the bitmaps looking the same, but I really don't know what that would be useful for. If there's something else I should add or change, just ask.

Comment: do you put some sample here?

Comment: So is that really your problem? Ok, I've got to go to school now but after that i can add some

Comment: yes please, i am really stuck for long time with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to continuously change the bitmap when you click the button you can create a new thread and do it like that:

make your current activity implement Runnable

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements Runnable
{
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    //...
}
```

then create a method inside the activity like this:

```
public void run()
{
    while(running)
    {
        //Start Time
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_A)){
            bitmap = img_B.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
         else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_B)){
             bitmap = img_C.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
             image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
         else if(imagesAreEqual(bmp, img_C)){
             bitmap = img_D.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
             image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }

        //End Time
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (endTime -startTime < 1000/30)
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000/30 -(endTime -startTime));
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

Also when the button is clicked apply the following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bitmap img_A = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_a);
    Bitmap img_B = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_b);
    Bitmap img_C = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_c);
    Bitmap img_D = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_d);

    thread = new Thread(this);
    running = true;
    thread.start();
}
```

This will make your code check the image 30 times each second, if you want to change how fast it checks change the "1000/30" on the `run()` method (it counts in milliseconds)

Although I'm not sure I recommend something like this because checking so many bitmaps continuously is very cpu intensive, but if it solves your problem I guess it's worth it.

Also I'm not sure I understand your problem 100%, you can also try to run the check  just once each time a bitmap changes, if that's the case drop a comment and I will edit my answer.

Comment: @jack did it work as you wanted to? did it solve your problem?

Comment: when i fill color over imageview then can't change next compared bitmap object.

Comment: @jack I'm sorry, I don't understand could you explain a little better?

Comment: i implement your code dude, but when i fill color on imageview then after i can't go to next bitmap object and image is not changed. I think after filling color, bitmap object is not match.

Comment: is any other solution?

Comment: if you want apk or whole code then i am able to give you.

Comment: @jack I'm not sure if I understand what's not working with my answer, even if you give me your code I don't know what you are looking for.

Comment: There are two button(next,previous) for changing (Bitmap object)image(A,B,C,D). It's done when not fill color over imageview. But when i fill or draw with color on imageview background image then do not change next or previous image(A->B) using next button's click event.

Comment: @jack I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to solve that, I did my best to give you an answer to help, if that is not helpful I'm afraid I can't help anymore :(